# Facebook API/SDK like posts as of v2.8

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to develop an android app, that displays posts of a public Facebook page and enables logged in users to like these posts.

I tried to use the POST API call [`/{object-id}/likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes), but as of version 2.8 of the Facebook API the documentation says, that ...

> ... as of Nov 17, 2016 [Facebook] changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens.

My first guess is, that Facebook does this to avoid apps from abusing the "like" feature. In my understanding it's only possible to like posts on pages, where the logged in Facebook user also has page access rights (a Page Access Token) to. That seems to be a very restrictive option that impedes the possibility of an app to like posts.

I also tried to use the LikeView (as recommended in the Android sharing documentation), but that seems to only work for external links, which seems to be an Open Graph object. The documentation says:

> The Like button can be used to like a *Facebook Page* or any *Open Graph object* and can be referenced by URL or ID. [emphasis added by author]

When I use the `LikeView` on Facebook links, as returned by the `/{page-id}/posts` (`link` attribute on returned objects), the web view popup closes immediately after clicking on the `LikeView` button.

I'm posting this question, because I can't find any suitable information for liking Facebook posts (especially as of v2.8) via a custom Android app, even though (I think) this should be a basic feature because on Facebook liking things is one of the most used features.

Disclaimer: Sorry for not linking to more Facebook documentation references, but because of my reputation I'm not allowed to post more than one link.

Comment: _"because I can't find any suitable information for liking Facebook posts "_ - you found the relevant info already: It is not possible any more via API.

Comment: That was one of my fears, but I can't imagine that Facebook doesn't enable other (possibly big) apps to like posts. If this is part of the Facebook policy to prevent app from liking posts, i guess it should be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: It _is_ mentioned, on the very page you linked to, and here as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#nov-17th--2016. It was possible up until now, but now they removed it, because it was abused too much.

Comment: "The Graph API behavior of POST and DELETE to {object-id}/likes has changed to only be accessible for Page Access Tokens".  

What does the restriction for Page Access Tokens mean? Is my interpretation above correct?

Comment: It means that you can only perform these actions in the name of a page now, and not any more for a user.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Can you please summarize your comments into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the relevant info already: It is not possible any more via API.

It was possible up until now, but now they removed it, because it was abused too much.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#nov-17th--2016:

> Deprecations
>
> - The Graph API behavior of POST and DELETE to {object-id}/likes has changed to only be accessible for Page Access Tokens. You can read more about this in our [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes).

That means, only liking in the name of a page is still possible; but not any more in the name of a user.